# function is not returning what is intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

The function that I created is to measure the length of an argument!. I want to return "Sorry, integers don't have length"

```
def string_length(mystring):
    if type(mystring) == int:
         return "Sorry, integers don't have length"
    else:
         return len(mystring)

mystring = input("what is the value ?")
print(string_length(mystring))
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't pass it an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but this should work, if my understanding is not wrong:

```
def string_length(mystring):
    try:
      if type(int(mystring)) == int:
        return "Sorry, integers don't have length"
      elif type(mystring) == str:
        return len(mystring)
    except:
      return len(str(mystring))
mystring = input("what is the value ?")
print(string_length(mystring))
```

Comment: `type(int(mystring)) == int` is always true, though. I think you just masked the problem with a try-except

Answer (score 0):

In Python2, `input` will evaluate to an integer, not a string, which would explain the message.

You can use `hasattr` to check for the `__len__` magic function rather than doing explict type checking.

This should work for any iterable type, I believe

```
def string_length(mystring):
  if hasattr(mystring, '__len__'):
    return len(mystring)
  else:
    print("Sorry, {} don't have length".format(type(mystring)))
    return None

mystring = input("what is the value ?")
print(string_length(mystring))
```

Then, make sure you are running this in Python3